# Можно ли применить к include() фильтры take() и skip()

Tags: c#, linq

В принципе в названии вопрос ясен, есть список, у элемента списка есть еще список, из бд мне нужно получить ограниченное количество элементов из списка элемента, сори за тофтологию, надеюсь понятно объяснил, так вот, если через инклуд нельзя, то как вообще это делается? Проект Asp.net core

Comment: Вы прбовали применить? Оно работает?

Comment: @tym32167 нет не работает,ставлю ограничения, все равно выдает весь список, пишут что в еф нет функции для ограничения вложенных списков, но... как тогда быть? Каким способом не нагружать бд,например у юзера список друзей, всписке миллион записей, как передать только 100, ведь должны быть способы?

Comment: Добавьте код, как вы пытались. Укажите платформу, библиотеку, провайдер который использовали.

Comment: @tym32167 хорошо, сейчас не дома,  утром загружу,

Comment: @tym32167 хотяс телефона напишу сам запрос, var `friends = _db.Users.include(x=》 x.UserFriends).Theninclude(x=》 x.Friend).Skip(1).Take(5).FirstOrDefault(x=》 x.Id == id)` это сам запрос из на получения юзера из бд с ограниченымсписком его друзей, но это не работает, ошибок нет,но я получаю весь список без ограничений,утром закину код подробнее

Comment: EF? EF Core? LinqToXML? :)

Comment: @tym32167 ef core,сорь сразу что то не додумался уточнить...

Comment: [Раз](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43638003/312041), [два](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39637702/312041). По сути вы можете использовать проекцию или искать стороннюю либу.

Comment: @tym32167 оформил ответ, спс как всегда!

Answer (score 0):

в общем получить юзера с ограниченным количеством его друзей у меня получилось только при помощи сторонней библиотеки, а именно - EntityFramework-Plus и ее метода IncludeFilter, в итоге я ведь ничего не гружу лишнего? В результате получаю юзера и "size" друзей.

```
var currentUser = db.Users
                .IncludeFilter(x => x.UserFriends
                .Where(z => z.UserId == id)
                .Take(size)
                .Select(c => c.Friend))
                .Where(x => x.Id == id)
                .ToList()
                .FirstOrDefault();
```

А потом меня ткнули носом в то, на сколько просто это было сделать вот так:

```
var currentUser = db.Users.Where(x => x.UserFriends.Any(z => z.FriendId == id)).Skip((page - 1) * size)
                .Take(size).ToList();
```